# POST http://localhost:3000/api/v1/register 500 (Internal Server Error) xhr.js:220

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

Register route is working fine without cloudinary with POSTMAN, but as I add Cloudinary to add files, I am getting the mentioned error and every time I am getting following constants as message
REQUEST_USER_REQUEST and then REQUEST_USER_FAIL

userAction.jsx -- register

```
// Register
export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_REQUEST });
  
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
  
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/register`, userData, config);
  
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
};
```

SignUp

```
import React, {Fragment,useRef,useState, useEffect} from "react";
import "./LoginSignUp.css";
import Loader from "../layout/Loader/Loader";
import { Link, useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import LockOpenIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LockOpen';
import EmailIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Email';
import PersonIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Person';
import img from "../../images/Profile.png";
import {useSelector, useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import {clearErrors, login , register} from "../../actions/userAction.jsx";
import {useAlert} from "react-alert";
 

export default function LoginSignUp() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const alert = useAlert();
    const navigate = useNavigate();
  
  
    const [avatar, setAvatar] = useState(img);
    const [avatarPreview, setAvatarPreview] = useState(img);

  
    const registerSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      const myForm = new FormData();
  
      myForm.set("name", name);
      myForm.set("email", email);
      myForm.set("password", password);
      myForm.set("avatar", avatar);
      dispatch(register(myForm));
    };
  
    const registerDataChange = (e) => {
      if (e.target.name === "avatar") {
        const reader = new FileReader();
  
        reader.onload = () => {
          if (reader.readyState === 2) {
            setAvatarPreview(reader.result);
            setAvatar(reader.result);
          }
        };
  
        reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0]);
      } else {
        setUser({ ...user, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
      }
    };
  
    useEffect(() => {
      if (error) {
        alert.error(error);
        dispatch(clearErrors());
      }
      if (isAuthenticated) {
        navigate("/account");
      }
    }, [dispatch, error, alert, navigate, isAuthenticated]);
  
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {loading ? (
          <Loader />
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
                <form
                  className="signUpForm"
                  encType="multipart/form-data"
                  onSubmit={registerSubmit}
                >
                  <div className="signUpName">
                    <PersonIcon />
                    <input
                      type="text"
                      placeholder="Name"
                      required
                      name="name"
                      value={name}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="signUpEmail">
                    <EmailIcon />
                    <input
                      type="email"
                      placeholder="Email"
                      required
                      name="email"
                      value={email}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <div className="signUpPassword">
                    <LockOpenIcon />
                    <input
                      type="password"
                      placeholder="Password"
                      required
                      name="password"
                      value={password}
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
  
                  <div id="registerImage">
                    <img src={avatarPreview} alt="Avatar Preview" />
                    <input
                      type="file"
                      name="avatar"
                      accept="image/*"
                      onChange={registerDataChange}
                    />
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" value="Register" className="signUpBtn" />
                </form>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </Fragment>
    );
  };
```

Backend Register User Route

```
exports.registerUser = catchAsyncErrors(async (req, res, next) => {

  if (req.files) {
    const avatar= req.files.avatar;
    req.body = { ...req.body, avatar};
  }

  const myCloud = await cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(req.body.avatar, {
    folder: "avatars",
    width: 150,
    crop: "scale",
  });

  const { name, email, password } = req.body;

  const user = await User.create({
    name,
    email,
    password,
    avatar: {
      public_id: myCloud.public_id,
      url: myCloud.secure_url,
    },
  });

  sendToken(user, 201, res);
});
```

1. Cloudinary Name, API_KEY and SECRET is present.
2. Included body-parser and express-fileupload.

Comment: So what is your backend logging as the reason for the 500?

Comment: Internal Server Error

Comment: If that's the only message that gets logged _on the backend_ (which I doubt), you need to think about your error logging. We can't help you with backend issues if all you have are frontend messages.

Answer (score 0):

Your post is wrong.

Instead of posting: `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/register`

It should be: `http://localhost:3000/api/v2/register`

You see in your **Backend Register User Route** you are using v2 of cloudinary but trying to post v1 of cloudinary:

In your **userAction.js** Instead of:

```
// Register
export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_REQUEST });
  
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
  
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v1/register`, userData, config);
  
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
};
```

Try:

```
// Register
export const register = (userData) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_REQUEST });
  
      const config = { headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" } };
  
      const { data } = await axios.post(`/api/v2/register`, userData, config);
  
      dispatch({ type: REGISTER_USER_SUCCESS, payload: data.user });
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch({
        type: REGISTER_USER_FAIL,
        payload: error.response.data.message,
      });
    }
};
```